# Does it make sense to say "Me too" as a reply to "I love you?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

- "I love Tom."
- "Me too."

It means "I love Tom, too." doesn't it?  Then, how about the case below?

- "I love you."
- "Me too."

Does it mean "I love you, too." or "I love myself, too"?  Does it make sense to say "Me too" here?

Comment: It would **not make sense** to reply to 'I love you' with 'me too', and would severely disappoint (and possibly annoy) the first person. The only thing to say (if true) is 'I love you too'.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the reply ***Me too*** in such contexts should mean ***I love me as well.*** But not everyone feels comfortable replying with, say, ***Ditto***, so you might just have to get used to the usage. It's pointless / pedantic to say it doesn't make sense when it's relatively common ***and*** the intended meaning is obvious.

Comment: If this was the first such declaration, I would (as the first speaker) find 'me too' rather disappointing and flippant.

Comment: @Lambie you're right about it being normal to replace the "I" with "me too", but the distinction being made here is with phrases where the word "you" would change to refer to a different person. To me, "me too" sounds "off" and confusing if it would mean changing the meaning of another pronoun than the "me".

Comment: What @Lambie said. This question is starting to look like a peeve.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And it was so annoying when the main character said it every episode in _Dexter_...

Answer (score 2):

In everyday speech, people often say "Me too" in response to things like: I love you, I like that, I see it, etc. etc. etc. And what is meant is: I love you too. I like it too. I see it too.

Of course, if a person says: "I love you" and you want to say the same thing back to them, **you can say in standard English**: "I love you too" or "I also love you." But in the real world, many  people just say: "Me, too." That is just a fact of English life [a joke but true]. "Me, too" can also be read as "Me, I love you too."